# Duplicate entry with form choices

Tags: php, symfony

I have a classified with categories. My classified can have one or several categories:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="classified", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $categories;
```

An important thing to know is that my **Category entity has composite primary keys** : the ID of the category, and the classified.

I want to populate categories into my classified with a choices field:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('categories', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'Category 1' => 1,
            'Category 2' => 2,
            'Category 3' => 3,
            'Category 4' => 4,
        ],
        'multiple' => true,
    ])->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        // Transform collection of entities into an array of IDs
        function($categories) {
            if (!$categories) {
                return [];
            }

            return $categories->map(function(Category $category) {
                return $category->getId();
            })->toArray();
        },
        // Reverse transform IDs array from request to a collection of entities
        function($categories) {
            $items = [];
            if ($categories && is_array($categories)) {
                foreach ($categories as $id) {
                    $items[] = new Category($id);
                }
            }

            return $items;
        }
    ))
);
```

As you can see I have a transformer to convert the categories collection to a list of ID, and vice versa.

Everything is fine during the creation of my classified, but **edition is bugged**.

My problem is that when I submit the form, I have duplicate entries issues:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tv_classified_category (id, classified_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [4, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here is what I found when I dump the list of categories before and after `handleRequest`:

```
    dump($classified->getCategories()->toArray());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        dump($classified->getCategories()->toArray());
```

Debug result:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Category {#1036 ▶}
  1 => Category {#1038 ▶}
]

array:3 [▼
  2 => Category {#4108 ▶}
  3 => Category {#4110 ▶}
]
```

As you can see, there is a strange **mismatch between keys**, and the PHP i**ds of objects are differents** before and after the handleRequest call. What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the problem is that when an item is removed then added again in the collection, it causes a duplicate entry because Doctrine performs inserts before deletions.

To fix my problem, I need to make sure that same Category objects are used if my categories already in the classified. The only way I found to do this is some uggly code that will probably be broken one day. I hope anybody will find a better way to do this than the code bellow.

```
    // Add the listener on the categories field (a ChoiceType field)
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $categories = $form->getData();

        $classified = $form->getParent()->getData();
        $classifiedCategories = [];
        foreach ($classified->getCategories() as $classifiedCategory) {
            $classifiedCategories[$classifiedCategory->getId()] = $classifiedCategory;
        }

        $modelData = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $modelData->add($classifiedCategories[$category->getId()] ?? $category);
        }

        // This is uggly, don't reproduce this at home kids :)
        $refProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($form, 'modelData');
        $refProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $refProperty->setValue($form, $modelData);
    })
```

I need to do this stuff in POST_SUBMIT (and use Reflection) because in SUBMIT I only get the flat view data and not the ArrayCollection.